# What's wrong with sorted set code? My output should match sample

Tags: java

Can anyone help on what's wrong with my code? Only the first input number shows up when I run it (it doesn't create a sorted list), the delete command isn't working, and the 'true' 'false' in exists command doesn't show up. My output should match the given sample I put at the end.

The areas I had to fill in to make the code work are the areas after the TODOTODOTODO symbols which would be 44-61, 75-83, 97-105. I'm not sure where I went wrong in those areas and why it is not working correctly to give the desired output?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

// Defines the a Sorted Set collection and implements a driver program in main
public class SortedSet {
    // Define a basic element of a linked list
    private class LinkedNode {
        int x;  // Value stored in the node
        LinkedNode next;  // Reference to the next node in the list
    }
    
LinkedNode front = null;  // Reference to the front of the singly linked list

// Adds the integer x to the collection.
// The resulting collection is sorted in increasing order and
// does not contain any duplicate values.
public void add(int x) {
    // Initialize a new node to be added to the collection
    LinkedNode newNode = new LinkedNode();
    LinkedNode cur = front;
    newNode.x = x;
    
    // Check if list is empty
    if (cur == null) {
        front = newNode;
    } 
    // If list is not empty, check if node should be placed in front
    else if (front != null) {
        if (newNode.x < front.x) {
            newNode.next = front;
            front = newNode;
        }
        
        // If not in front, check for the middle or the end, or duplicate.
        else {
            // <TODO><TODO><TODO> 
            LinkedNode temp = cur;
            LinkedNode prev = cur;
            int middle = x;
            while (temp != null) {
                if(temp.x > newNode.x) {
                    middle = 1;
                    newNode.next = temp;
                    prev.next = newNode;
                }
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp.next;
                }
            if (middle == 0) {
                prev = newNode;
                }
            }
        }
    }
            
// Deletes the integer x from the sorted set.
// The remaining collection remains sorted and without duplicates.
public void delete(int x){
    // Declare a new reference and initialize it to the front of the list
    LinkedNode cur = front;
    
    // Check if list is empty
    if (front == null) {
        System.out.print("There is nothing to delete!");
    } else {  // Not empty
        // Go through list, checking whether node is in the list, and delete if found
        // <TODO><TODO><TODO>
        LinkedNode prev = new LinkedNode();
        while (cur.x != x && cur != null) {
            prev = cur;
            cur = cur.next;
            }
        if (cur != null)
            prev.next = cur.next;
        }
    }

// Returns true if the integer x exists in the sorted set and false otherwise.
public void exists(int x) {
    // Declare a new reference and initialize it to the front of the list
    LinkedNode cur = front;
    
    // Check if list is empty.
    if (front == null) {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
    
    // If not empty, check for the node.
    // <TODO><TODO><TODO>
    else {
        while (cur != null) {
            if (cur.x==x)
                return;
            cur=cur.next;
            }
        return;
    }
}

// Returns a string representing the sorted set as a space separated list.
public String toString() {
    String s = "";
    
    LinkedNode cur = front;     
    while (cur!=null) {
        s+= cur.x + " ";
        cur = cur.next;
    }
    
    return s;
}

// Driver method
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Declare variables
    SortedSet sortedSet = new SortedSet();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] tokens;
    String command;
    int num;
    
    // Print header info
    System.out.println("Programming Fundamentals\n"
            + "NAME: Andres Reyes\n"
            + "PROGRAMMING ASSIGNMENT 4\n");
            
    // Enter command loop
    while (true) {
        // Prompt the user for a command
        System.out.print("Enter command: ");
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        
        // Parse input
        if (input.equals("q")) break;  // user quits
        tokens = input.split("\\s");
        if (tokens.length < 2) continue; // invalid input
        command = tokens[0];
        num = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
        
        // Execute command
        if (command.equals("add")){
            sortedSet.add(num);
            System.out.println(sortedSet);
        } else if (command.equals("del")) {
            sortedSet.delete(num);
            System.out.println(sortedSet);
        } else if (command.equals("exists")) {
            sortedSet.exists(num);
        } else {
            System.out.print("Command does not exist");
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("\nGood bye!");
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I made following changes in the add-function and they got it working for me:

```
// If not in front, check for the middle or the end, or duplicate.
     else {
         // <TODO><TODO><TODO> 
         LinkedNode temp = cur.next; // start at cur.next as your temp-variable
         LinkedNode prev = cur;
         int middle = 0; // set middle to 0
         while (temp != null) {
             if(temp.x > newNode.x) {
                 middle = 1;
                 newNode.next = temp;
                 prev.next = newNode;
             }
             prev = temp;
             temp = temp.next;
          }
         if (middle == 0) {
             // add node to the end
             prev.next = newNode;
          }
         }
     }
```

You have to start at cur.next as your temp-variable.

As far as I can see, you're not yet checking if there are any duplicate values in your list.

**Edit:** I didn't work on the exists-method, which is not giving you any output at the moment. The problem is simply that you're generating any output while you're checking if a value exists in your list. You could either write a System.out.print which prints "true" in case the value was found or "false" in case if wasn't. Or you change the return type of the exists-function to boolean, return a boolean according to the result and print the return value.

It might also help you to visualize a linked list to unterstand why you have to change the temp-variable to cur.next. I think https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/linked_lists_algorithm.htm gives a good explaination of the insertion process.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some hints. The main problem I see with this code is that you really need a reference to the start of the LinkedList (the head) would be the only way to print the list and check for duplicates.

The following should be added to your class

```
LinkedList head = null; //start of the list
```

Then you have to update your toString() or you will never print the correct elements in your list no matter what you do. Try this:

```
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    LinkedNode current = head;
    while(current != null){
        output.append(current.x).append(" ");
        current = current.next;
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

You have to be really careful when you are appending to a String in a loop because Strings are immutable. Everytime you are appending to a list you are creating a new String. Instead, use `StringBuilder`.

```
//s+= cur.x + " ";
```

Your add method should handle the following cases:

**Case 1: List is empty: ( don't forget to set ref to head)**

**Case 2: new element is great than front of list**

**Case 3: new element is less than current head**

**Case 4: new element is less than current and greater than head**